# Dynamically add items to Ionic 2 side menu

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

So I am new to angular 2 and ionic 2. I am trying to make a button on that will add favorites to the ionic 2 side menu. I tried using the @Output event put couldnt get that to work. Any ideas would be helpful thank you.

Comment: What does the content of the menu depend on? I mean, what makes a button appear/disappear? Have you tried `*ngIf`?

Comment: clicking on a like button on another view to add to the side menu list. im not able to use @output sense im not using the other view as a template.

Comment: you should think on where will you store the state of the buttons you want to show on the side menu. You could have a Service (`@Injectable`) where you can add buttons to it and the side menu component have a watch on that list. Then wherever you have the like button, `(click)` event will add a button in there. Makes sense?

Comment: @ olivarra Yeah I get that i need a service to pass the data but I havent been successful with subscribing to the updated data in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here in Ionic2 v2.1.14. Attempting to place this inside the constructor of the root component

```html
        userDataProvider.getUserData().subscribe(user_data => {
            console.log("(app) user_data: ", user_data);
            this.user_data = user_data;
        })
```

...Hours have been burned trying to locate the origin of this error:

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userDataProvider.getUserData().subscribe')

Comment: is this an answer to the question or another question?